# Flutter DrawerHeader Text Overflow

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I have this issue with my Flutter UI. I'm trying to make my text break when it's too long, but the overflow ellipsis doesn't work. Can you help me please?

issue picture:

[image]

this is what i'm looking for:

[image]

My code:

```dart
    static Drawer myDrawer (BuildContext context, String mode, String businessName) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0),
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.17,
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: DrawerHeaderPaint(),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 25),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          radius: 30,
                          child: Image(
                            height: 40,
                            image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png')
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'My Companny',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: 25
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.apartment, color: Color(0xff263d67)),
                                  Text(
                                    'Business Name tooooo loooooong',
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    softWrap: false,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                      color: Color(0xffd7d7d7),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 40),
                menuOptions(),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: try, Business Name Container wrap to Flexible

Comment: Flexible ,Expanded or https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping Business Info Column with `Expanded` widget and also wrap `Text` widget after apartment icon with `Expanded` widget, like so:

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      const Text(
        'My Companny',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          fontSize: 25,
        ), //TextStyle
      ), //Text
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: const [
            Icon(Icons.apartment, color: Color(0xff263d67)),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                'Business Name tooooo loooooong',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
                softWrap: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  color: Color(0xffd7d7d7),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),  //TextStyle
              ),  //Text 
            ),  //Expanded
          ],  
        ),  //Row         
      ),  //Container
    ],
  ),  //Column
),  //Expand
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Expanded or Flexible

```
  Expanded(
      child:
        Text('Business Name tooooo loooooong',...))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can use the SizedBox widget and specify your text width it helps to ellipsis the text. Hope this code will help you.Thanks  
        import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
            import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            
            class Dermo extends StatefulWidget {
              const Dermo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
            
              @override
              _DermoState createState() => _DermoState();
            }
            
            class _DermoState extends State<Dermo> {
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  )
                    ,
                    drawer: Drawer(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        child: Container(
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.17,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(width: 25),
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  radius: 30,
                                  child: Image(
                                      height: 40, image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png')),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'My Companny',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                          fontSize: 25),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(Icons.apartment, color: Color(0xff263d67)),
                                          ///if you  want to show complete text use can comment 
                                          ///out overflow,softWrap and maxLines otherwise you can use all 
                                          ///these properties it ellipsis the text
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 160,
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Business Name tooooo loooooong',
                                             /* overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              softWrap: false,*/
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                                color: Color(0xffd7d7d7),
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 40),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )));
              }
            }
```